# lines in a file with comma

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to know how to create a sub file with a number of commas, for example.

**123,abc,qwe,ert**

**123,456,abc,qwe,fgh**

I want to create a file .txt with the line that has 4 commas. (123,456,abc,qwe,fgh).

I tried with this.

awk -F\, '{print NF-1}'

But only gives me the number of commas that each line has.

Comment: `awk -F, 'NF==5 {print > "file.txt"}' f `to print the line which has 4 commas.

Answer (score 3):

four delimiters mean five fields, use as a condition, by default it will print the matching lines...

```
awk -F, 'NF==5' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk -F, 'NF==5 {print > "file.txt"}' f

cat file.txt
123,456,abc,qwe,fgh
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all commas with commas and count the occurrences and compare:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/,/,",")==4' file
123,456,abc,qwe,fgh
```

Comment: Btw, oh great ones: this seems to work `gsub(",",",")` (at least on my gawk) but is there any difference to `gsub(/,/,",")`?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a file .txt with the line that has 4 commas.

Alternative `sed` approach:

```
cat testfile | sed -En 's/^([^,]+,){4}[^,]*$/&/p' > file.txt
```